# Reactjs Get the stored value from a store through redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'd like to save the value that I typed and submitted through redux and get the value on the another component. How can I do it in this situation??

plus It'd be really appreciated if you explain when its an object,or when its an array. Thank you!

```
// AddName.js
state = {
   user: ''
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(
        { [name]: value }
    );
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
   const userName = this.state.user;
   const name = {
       userName: userName
   }
   this.props.dispatch({
       type: 'ADD_NAME'
       userName
   })
}

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      name="user"
      value={this.state.user}
   />
</form>

export default connect()(AddName);
```

.

```
// addNameReducer.js
const addName = (state = {}, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NAME':
        console.log("add_name");
        return { userName: action.userName };
    default:
        return state;
   }
 }

 export default addName;
```

.

```
//anotherComponent.js
<p> {I want the stored value here } </p>
export default anotherComponent;
```

Comment: Didn't get your question about object/array but have answered your main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `connect()` function from `react-redux` package to connect your component to redux store. It accepts `mapStateToProps` function as a first argument which is used to pass the values from the store to your component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userName = state.userName
});

connect(mapStateToProps)(AnotherComponent);
```

Now `AnotherComponent` will receive `userName` as a prop:

```
export default const AnotherComponent = props => <p>{props.userName}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the mapStateToProps! Don't worry about second-question. It came from lack of basic programming knowledge. gotta study hard. haha Have a good day!